# Multilingual user interface: Is it possible to Export Translations using PowerShell?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, stsadm, multilingual

I have a SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise with several language packs installed. The Alternate Languages have been enabled in the Site Settings and several items have been translated.

Is it possible to perform the action "Export Translations" using Site Settings > Site Administration > Export Translations using a PowerShell or STSADM command?

The same question also applies for using the action "Import Translations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box of PowerShell cmdlets, It can't be done. It's no valid cmdlets in the [Index of SharePoint Server 2010 Windows PowerShell cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678226%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

However, Stefan Goßner wrote the blog post [SharePoint Variations – The complete Guide – Part 16 – Translation Support](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/12/02/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-16-translation-support.aspx) which go over the topic in detail. He suggest to use PublishingService to export/import translations

> ## Export/Import using the PublishingService
>
> To allow automated translation of content SharePoint provides the export and import funcationality also through the ExportObjects and ImportObjects methods of the PublishingService web service which can be accessed using the following URL:
>
> `http://servername/site/_vti_bin/PublishingService.asmx`
>
> There is good documentation on how to use the web service for export and import on MSDN:
>
> - PublishingService.[ExportObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webservices.publishingservice.exportobjects.aspx) Method
> - PublishingService.[ImportObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webservices.publishingservice.importobjects.aspx) Method

But to convert this to PowerShell methods take some effort and I havn't seen this done. I would write Console application instead to solve the problem at hand if you don't like to use Export Translation in your SharePoint GUI.

Comment: The problem is that using the SharePoint GUI to export the translations gives me an error. So I hoped there would be another way to export the translations.

Comment: @TempaC So I guess you have some errors in your farm needed to be fixed to be able to use the control. Have you checked the health analyzer in your farm?

Comment: I'm going to award you the bounty since you've confirmed it is not possible using out of the box powershell or stsadm commands.

Comment: @TempaC Thank you. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.